# How to compute a line intersection point in a street layer in PostGIS 1.4?

Tags: postgis

I have a street layer downloaded from OSM. I need to calculate intersection point as we do in QGIS from `vector menu -> Analysis tool -> Line intersections`.

I am new to PostGIS/PostgreSQL, I managed to download and install it spending whole day on Ubuntu machine. Using `shp2psql-gui` I imported data with pgAdmin3.

I know how to do in QGIS, but tell me how to do the same in PostGIS.  I have heard some st_intersects etc. but it can't help. I want to return something like this.

Below are snapshot for more clearer picture of my issue. Blue indicates street layer.

[image: road network]

```
name_1 | name_2 | laitude | longitude
xyz st | abc st | #value| #value
lmn st | pqr st | #value| #value
xyz st | pqr st | #value| #value
pqr st | abc st | #value| #value
lmn st | xyz st | #value| #value
lmn st | abc st | #value| #value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for ST_Intersection, not ST_Intersects.

http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Intersection.html

also:

http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersection.html

If you have lines that intersect at multiple locations (sometimes it happens), you may need to look into ST_Dump to get all of those intersection points.

The query might look like this (not tested, and you should include IDs as well as street names in your resulting tables):

```
SELECT name_1, name_2, ST_X(points) AS latitude, ST_Y(points) AS longitude
FROM
(
  SELECT name_1, name_2, (ST_Dump(possiblePoints)).geom AS points
  FROM
  (
    SELECT A.StreetName AS name_1, B.StreetName AS name_2, ST_Intersection(A.geom, B.geom) AS possiblePoints
    FROM   LinesTable A
           INNER JOIN
           LinesTable B
           ON ST_Intersects(A.geom,B.geom)
              AND
              A.ID <> B.ID
  ) AS X
) AS XX
```

Comment: thanks but still i am struggle to get what i want as posted in question. and there are not two different layer involved. i have only line layer from which i want that intersection points.

Comment: can i have the piece of code so that i can write according my situation.

Comment: getting something error like `ERROR: cross-database references are not implemented: a.geom.st_intersects`

Comment: oops something like this now `ERROR:  operator does not exist: boolean = integer
LINE 11:            ON ST_Intersects(A.geom,B.geom) = 1
                                                    ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
********** Error **********

ERROR: operator does not exist: boolean = integer
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
Character: 363`

Comment: i think there are still exist sql server syntax. nw it returns `ERROR:  function st_x(geometry_dump) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT name_1, name_2, ST_X(points) AS latitude, ST_Y(points...
                               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

********** Error **********

ERROR: function st_x(geometry_dump) does not exist
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Character: 24`

Comment: thanks for continue support. it returs now `ERROR:  Argument to X() must be a point`

Comment: Is it possible you have lines with different IDs that overlap, so that the intersection is a line? Is it possible you have polygons in your street table?

Comment: No, there are only single layer of lines.

Comment: Error is something like `ERROR:  Argument to X() must be a point
********** Error **********

ERROR: Argument to X() must be a point
SQL state: XX000
`

Comment: I suppose you could look at the resulting geometry from the query the creates group X.  This would help to determine what geometries you are dealing with.  A single layer of lines may still overlap themselves.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16061/discussion-between-user1586957-and-ike).

Comment: i found it works with `ST_Centroid` in`(ST_Dump(ST_Centroid(test.possiblePoints))).geom` . kindly share your view whether it is okay or not.

Comment: But it doent return spatial point data. its only returns tabular data.

Comment: You requested a table of "name_1", "name_2", "latitude", "longitude".  Just put geom in your top selection criteria and you will get points.