# Query road shape

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap

We have downloaded data from Openstreetmap and want to make special queries but have no idea how to start. What we want to do is find all road intersections with a certain angle in Australia. For example the input would be:

- mostly straight segment1 of approx. 7km
- mostly straight segment2 of approx 5km
- we know that these segments intersect each other at an angle of 30 degrees.

How can we find all intersections that satisfy this condition? We would like to use Postgis but really any solution would be ok.

Comment: Here is [something](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25126/how-to-calculate-the-angle-at-which-two-lines-intersect-in-postgis) to get you started. Shout if you have questions.

Comment: It http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/108772/how-to-compute-a-line-intersection-point-in-a-street-layer-in-postgis-1-4 will give you a clue for getting intersection points.